# Check npm version in Docker

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I have built an image with Dockerfile, it looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.18.1
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update 
RUN apt-get -y install curl 
RUN npm install 
ENTRYPOINT ["curl"]
```

Now I can see that curl is installed, but how can I check on Node?
Every time I am trying to see the version I get an error:

```
'node'/'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I also tried this:

```bash
docker run -it --rm node /bin/bash -c 'node --version'
```

but ended up with this:

```
--version': -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
--version': -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: You already _know_ the Node version, it's 12.8.1. That came with NPM 6.10.2 per https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/. Or just run `docker run --entrypoint bash node:12.8.1 -c '<thing> --version'`. Your first error is from Windows which suggests you ran it _outside_ the container, which doesn't make sense if you want to find out what's _inside_ the container.

Comment: (Also note Node 12.8.1 is _old_; if you really need Node 12 use v12.22.12, but even the next LTS version v14 is only supported for another few weeks.)